# Cannot create file in external storage

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a file in the external storage directory of the Nougat emulator. using the following code:

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test987689");
    if(!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
        Toast.makeText(this, "External SD card not mounted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }try {
        if (file.getParentFile().exists() || file.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Permissons:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:958)
W/System.err:     at com.vibhinna.sreni.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:41)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6658)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2584)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1445)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6044)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `targetSdkVersion` 23 or higher? Do you request the storage permission at runtime?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Ah. forgot about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your targetSdk is 23 or higher, you should request permissions dynamically.

to know more : [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: wow, it looks like the question about permissions is asked everywhere around the internet, but you are the only one, who helped to solve the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

to get File path you can use **Context.getExternalFilesDir()/Context.getExternalCacheDir()**

for example

`String path=Context.getExternalCacheDir()+"file.text";
File file=new File(path)`

it doesnt need permission if the filepath is "Android/data/app package/file name"